# Ways to prove $P\rightarrow (Q \lor R)$?

Tags: logic

I know that $P\rightarrow(Q\lor R)$ can be proved by proving $P\rightarrow Q$ or $P\rightarrow R$.

What I don't know is if this is also a valid proof:

$$((P\land\neg Q)\rightarrow R)\text{ or }((P\land\neg R)\rightarrow Q)$$

Or is this redundant?

Comment: $P \Rightarrow (Q \lor R)$ is equivalent to $\neg P \lor (Q \lor R)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment by @Andrew Li ,

$P\implies(Q\lor R)$ is equivalent to $\lnot P \lor Q \lor R,$ which is equivalent to  $\lnot P \lor Q \lor \lnot P \lor R;$

i.e., $(P \implies Q) \lor (P \implies R).$

Comment: This answers the question before it was edited

Answer (score 0):

Proof that ((∧¬)→) or ((∧¬)→) is redundant:

By contrapositive to both sides of the or we get:

(¬R => (¬P or Q)) or (¬Q => (¬P or R))

which is equal to:

(¬R => ¬P) or (¬R => Q) or (¬Q => ¬P) or (¬Q => R)

Which is equal to:

(R or ¬P) or (R or Q) or (Q or ¬P) or (Q or R)

Which is equal to:

R or ¬P or Q

Which is equal to:

(¬P or R) or (¬P or Q)

Which is equal to:

(P => R) or (P => Q)